# Could not read JSON: Unexpected character ('[' (code 91)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value

Tags: json

my Json code

```
{
    "referenceId":"referenceId0",
    "operation":"UPDATE",
    "circleList" [  
        {
            "circleCode":"RJ/OR/AP", 
            "circleName":"Rajasthan/Orissa/Andhra Pradesh"
        },
        {
            "circleCode":"RJ/OR/AP", 
            "circleName":"Rajasthan/Orissa/Andhra Pradesh",
        }
    ]
}

error message : {
   "responseCode": "1",
   "message": "System error: Could not read JSON: Unexpected character ('[' (code 91)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@157ba3f; line: 4, column: 16]; nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('[' (code 91)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@157ba3f; line: 4, column: 16]"
}
```

Comment: Step 1: At least *glance* at [the JSON format](http://json.org).

Comment: Try to validate the JSON using http://jsonlint.com/. I have added correct JSON below.

Answer (score 3):

`JSON` invalid, here

`"circleList" [`
need to add `:`

should be

`"circleList": [`

Comment: JSON is invalid, you have to add : as suggested above. Moreover, remove extra ,  "circleName":"Rajasthan/Orissa/Andhra Pradesh", should be  "circleName":"Rajasthan/Orissa/Andhra Pradesh". Therefore, valid JSON would be:{
 "referenceId": "referenceId0",
 "operation": "UPDATE",
 "circleList": [{
  "circleCode": "RJ/OR/AP",
  "circleName": "Rajasthan/Orissa/Andhra Pradesh"
 }, {
  "circleCode": "RJ/OR/AP",
  "circleName": "Rajasthan/Orissa/Andhra Pradesh"
 }]
}